# Retrieve nodes sharing multiple taxonomy terms

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Query Drupal 7 for nodes sharing **both** taxonomy terms(tid). I am querying the taxonomy_index tid and nid (and sorting it by created column). The taxonomy_index table has a column for tid and the corresponding nid tagged with that tid.

I have tried multiple combinations but all of them seem to either return all nodes tagged with either tid1 or tid2, or simply just tid1. Some of my code look like:

```
<!-- Query the taxonomy_index -->
$results = db_select('taxonomy_index', 't')
  ->fields('t', array('nid', 'tid'))
  ->distinct()
  ->condition('t.tid', $tids, 'IN')
  ->orderBy('t.created', 'DESC')
  ->extend('PagerDefault')
  ->limit(9)
  ->execute() 
  ->fetchCol();

<!-- Build the pager -->
$total = db_select('taxonomy_index', 't')
  ->fields('t', array('nid', 'tid'))
  ->distinct()
  ->condition('t.tid', $tids, 'IN')
  ->countQuery()
  ->execute() // Execute the query
  ->fetchCol(); // Fetch column
$total_pager = $total[0];

pager_default_initialize($total_pager,9);
```

I have also tried adding:

```
$query->where('t.tid = 115 AND t.tid = 210'); // Query for specific tids= 115 and 210.
```

Anybody know a solution to this? Or is there a preferred alternative like building up a new index table or perhaps make a new tid in another vocabulary that contains both (tid1 + tid2 = tid3)?

Comment: Hey you should accept that awesome answer down there. It helped me a lot! Nice question, too!

Answer (score 2):

You are right, the first example you give should return nodes which have the first or the second terms. The solution if you only want to filter on 2 terms is to do the query with a join.

In summary it should do a "first query" with the first term, then join on the same table with the nids from the first result and then filter on the second term.

```
$results = db_select('taxonomy_index', 't')
  ->fields('t', array('nid', 'tid'))
  ->condition('t.tid', $tid1); // Only take nodes with the first term.
// Now the result only contains nodes with one unique term ($tid1).
// We need all terms associated with the result nodes so we will make a left join.

// leftJoin doesn't return the query object so we can't chain it.
$results->leftJoin('taxonomy_index', 't2', 't.nid = t2.nid');
$results = $results->condition('t2.tid', $tid2)
  ->distinct()
  ->execute()
  ->fetchCol();
```

To explain it a little further imagine this data:

```
[{nid: 1, tid: 42}, {nid: 1, tid: 2014}, {nid: 2, tid: 42}, {nid: 3, tid: 1337}]
```

The first `->condition('t.tid', 42)` will give this:

```
[{nid: 1, tid: 42}, {nid: 2, tid: 42}]
```

So now you can't check on this result for other $tid, that is why we do a join on `'t.nid = t2.nid'`. It will give back all the info about the result of the first condition:

```
[{nid: 1, tid: 42}, {nid: 1, tid: 2014}, {nid: 2, tid: 42}]
```

Now we can finally add the second condition `$results->condition('t2.tid', 2014)` and it should return this:

```
[{nid: 1, tid: 2014}]
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this, convert the code to a SQL query and execute in PHPmyadmin or other similar interface. This is the great way to build a query to retrieve desired result!

Comment: Yeah I have tried that. My query is something like:


`SELECT t.nid AS nid, t.tid AS tid
FROM 
{taxonomy_index} t
WHERE  (t.tid = 115 AND t.tid = 210) 
ORDER BY t.created DESC`

However when I am querying with 2 or more tid it doesn't return anything.

Comment: I must say, you did you investigate further. You should check whether those terms are actually belongs to that particular node and try tids in separate queries! Btw. what made you 'downvote' my reply?